what is the problem with my hashtable in python?
i made a simple hashtable with linear probing consisting of key-list of values. i think there is a problem in either the insertion or the change method. I want to insert 20.000 keys with string names and a list of 8 integers for value. through the change method, i give a key, using linear probing its supposed to find the key value pair and change the values.i did that for 1.000.000 changes. But most of the keys dont change at all. only a few of them
class hashtable:
    def __init__(self, size):
        self.size = size
        self.data = [None] * size
        self.count = 0
    def hash_function(self, key):#Δίνω κλειδί, επιστρέφει το υπόλοιπο της διαίρεσης του κωδικοποιημένου (μέσω της hash) κλειδιού, για ναναι εντός ορίου
        hash_value = 0
        for char in key:
            hash_value = (hash_value * 31 + ord(char)) % self.size
        return hash_value 
    def insert(self, key):
        index = self.hash_function(key)

        # Linear probing
        while self.data[index] is not None:
            index = (index + 1) % self.size

        # Insert key and value
        self.data[index] = [key,[0]*8]
        self.count += 1
        if self.count > 0.7 * self.size:
            self.resize()
            return
    
    def change(self, key, price, week_day):
        index = self.hash_function(key)
        v = [price, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
        if (week_day == 'Δευτέρα'): v[2] = 1
        if (week_day == 'Τρίτη'): v[3] = 1 
        if (week_day == 'Τετάρτη'): v[4] = 1
        if (week_day == 'Πέμπτη'): v[5] = 1
        if (week_day == 'Παρασκευή'): v[6] = 1
        if (week_day == 'Σάββατο'): v[7] = 1
        original_index = index
    # Search for the key
        while self.data[index] is not None and self.data[index][0] != key:
            index = (index + 1) % self.size
        # If key is not found and we've looped back to the original position, return
            if index == original_index:
                return

    # Update value if the key is found
        if self.data[index] is not None and self.data[index][0] == key:
            values = self.data[index][1]
            result = [x + y for x, y in zip(v, values)]
            self.data[index][1] = result
        
    def resize(self):
        # Βρίσκω ελάχιστο πρώτο αριθμό, διπλάσιο από τον προηγούμενο
        new_size = self.size * 2
        while not self.is_prime(new_size):
            new_size += 1
        # Δημιουργία νέου πίνακα με νέο μέγεθος
        new_data = [None] * new_size
        # Βάζω τα ήδη υπάρχοντα keys στον νέο πίνακα
        for key,value in self:
            if key is not None:
                if isinstance(value,list):
                    index = self.hash_function(key)
                    while new_data[index] is not None:
                        index = (index + 1) % new_size  # Linear probing
                    new_data[index] = key, value
        # Ανανέωση μεγέθους και ζεύγων
        self.size = new_size
        self.data = new_data
    def is_prime(self, n):#Ελέγχω αν ένας αριθμός είναι πρώτος
        if n <= 1:
            return False
        elif n <= 3:
            return True
        elif n % 2 == 0 or n % 3 == 0:
            return False
        i = 5
        while i * i <= n:
            if n % i == 0 or n % (i + 2) == 0:
                return False
            i += 6
        return True
    
    def __iter__(self):#Μας επιτρέπει να ελέγξουμε τα ζεύγη σαν να είχαμε λεξικό, το κάνει iterable
        for item in self.data:
            if item is not None:
                yield item

I tried creating 20.000 hashtable items consisting of key-value and then doing 1.000.000 changes using the change function to random items. Most of the items never changed value. i think if it finds the key in one loop, it changes it, but when it need to linear prob, it doesnt. i am not sure.

Can you reproduce the problem with a smaller set of sample data?

Why don't you have a method to fetch the value of a key?

I think the problem is related to resizing.
